# How to take moment about point of contact in a hemisphere?

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-problem

[image]

[image]

How to get horizontal distance between point of contact and point P ?

Comment: Harshit Gupta. This seems to be a more Physics related problem as compared to Mathematics. Please ask this problem in the Physics SE.

Comment: It's a mechanical problem. It is from further maths paper 2

Comment: @DavidK Of course, your are correct, I must be half-asleep! I have deleted my comments.

Comment: @Sam It looks like a standard Mechanics problem to me and surely in the high school applied maths syllabus.

Comment: @DavidK if you found the answer then can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: @almagest No trouble. I have removed my comments as well since they are no longer needed.

Comment: @HarshitGupta The moment of a force about the point of contact $C$ is the force times the perpendicular distance of $C$ from the line of action of the force. Here there are two forces: one due to the small mass $m$ at $P$ and the other due to the hemisphere mass $M$. So in each case you have to find the horizontal distance of its (vertical) line of action from the point $C$.

Comment: @HarshitGupta You already showed the answer in the second screenshot in the question. It seems you need help understanding it. But do you require an explanation of moments from the very beginning of instruction on the topic (which would be asking to much for a question here, sorry) or from some other level of understanding? You might edit the question to show what you already know about calculating a moment. Given a force $F$ applied in some direction at some point $A$, how would you compute its moment about some other point $B$?

Comment: Thanks man i got it !!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the center of the hemisphere (on the circular face), $B$ the center of mass of the hemisphere, $C$ the point of contact.

Extend a horizontal line from $C$. Drop a vertical line from $A$ to meet the horizontal line at $D$. This same vertical line also goes through $B$.

So now the horizontal distance of either $A$ or $B$ to $C$ is known to equal the distance $CD.$

Consider triangle $\triangle ADC.$ It is a right triangle with hypotenuse $a$ and the angle at vertex $A$ (opposite the side $CD$) is $\alpha$. (Look at the relationships of perpendicular lines in the figure to see why.)
Now you can use the sine formula to find the length of $CD.$